# Approximate date column

Tags: postgresql

One of my customers would like to have a custom date column, where he could store the year only, a combination of month and year (without the day), or a classic date with day, month and year.

It should be possible to use this field for sorting the data. A "month-year" date should be considered as "01-month-year" for the sort, and a "year" date should be treated as "01-01-year" for the sort.

I could imagine two solutions to that:

- Store the date in the standard "day-month-year" format, and keep in a separate column how the date was entered ("year", "month-year", "day-month-year"), so the approximate date can be displayed exactly how it was entered.
- Use some sort of custom date column in the postgresql database.

Has anyone experience with that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use date-time functions to extract date components. I don't think it has any sense to create additional columns. Also, some databases allow to create indexes by functions.

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, an additional column is necessary if we want display the data exactly how it was entered, independently of how the date is stored in the database. Imagine the date entered is "2012". It might be stored in the database as "01-01-2012".

Comment: Do you mean you want to store a year only while month/day is unknown? In this case use ISO format YYYY-MM-DD, as a string. This format is good because it allows use string sorting for dates, because dates are in lexicographical order. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Also, you could store 2012-00-00 as a year-only entry, so it will be easy to determine from proper-date records.

Comment: Thanks Kan. The problem with 2012-0-0 is that it cannot be stored in a date column, it is "out of range". That means it would have to be stored in a string, and postgresql date/time calculation functions would not be available.

Comment: If you want to store a year only, there is no such type in the Postgres. So, just use a string type. What do you want from date/time functions then?